# Calling All Files From A Different Directory Located Above Domain Name Directory

Tags: php

I am attempting to create a script in PHP which reads and includes all files from a directory which is above the domain name directory.

For example:

My domain name is example.com and located in /var/www/html/example.com/ and I want /var/www/html/example.com/file.php to be able to read from:

- /var/www/html/videos/video1/ which contains index.html and the folders:

  - /var/www/html/videos/video1/images/ and /var/www/html/videos/video1/scripts/

e.g. www.example.com/file.php?dir=/var/www/html/videos/video1/index.html

If I use include (/var/www/html/videos/video1/index.html) it will only call the html file, which is done perfectly. However all the files in images folder and the scripts folders are not able to load.

I don't want to copy or call each file separately. I want to be able to only need to call index.html and then make the browser think it's in that directory and automatically read any file within there.

I know this works because Moodle uses this method (in file.php) to protect learning files by storing them in a moodledata folder which is one level above the public folder.
I've had a look but cannot make sense of it and I've searched the Internet to achieve the method I have explained above but have not had any success.

The reason I want to do this is to avoid having duplicate video files on the server for other sites that are hosted on the same server.
Many thanks in advance and for taking the time to assist.

Comment: If you are simply including the files the user supplies using the querystring you are doing it wrong.

Comment: the querystring will be called in a password protected area for admin purposes only. Moodle does this to protect the learning content. How would you advice me to do this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../");
```

This would be the directory you are looking for. Require files relative to that.

To output a different file look at [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) which outputs straight to the buffer or perhaps use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) which can be held in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Also file_get_contents includes the content of index.html but doesn't load the images and the scripts.
it needs to work so I can do this: www.example.com/file.php?dir=/var/www/html/videos/video1/index.html even if file.php was in any sub directory e.g. www.example.com/page/file.php
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can load an image in the browser directly, if you can it's probably a problem with your code, if you can't it may be a rights issue.